# How can i clear localStorage only avatar field when i upload avatar picture . React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, local-storage

Hello everyone when i change avatar picture in my proje . I can upload successfuly but because of localStorage data is not changing. I tried like that ;

```
this.state = {
  imageUrl: props.user && props.user.avatar,
};
```

my function like that

```
changeAvatar() {
  const profileDetail = cloneDeep(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('__PERSISTED_STORE__')));

  const isProfileDetailExist = profileDetail
    && profileDetail.user
    && profileDetail.user.signIn
    && profileDetail.user.info;

  if (isProfileDetailExist) {
    profileDetail.user.signIn.info.avatar = this.state.imageUrl;
  }

  localStorage.setItem('__PERSISTED_STORE__',
    JSON.stringify({
      user: profileDetail.user,
      language: profileDetail.language
    })
  );
}
```

how can i do it . My data seems like;

> Preferences : {  user: { singIn: {info : { ..... avatar inside there .
>   I want to change only avatar. language: ...

Comment: Can you provide code sandbox with with your problem or more code, like component in which you're using avatar and from where your're setting it?

Answer (score 0):

Problem is how you are setting your state

```
    this.state = {
  imageUrl: props.user && props.user.avatar,
};
```

From your code, imageUrl is boolean. If you want to assign avatar location (which is string), you shoud use

```
this.state = {
  imageUrl: props.user && props.user.avatar ? props.user.avatar: '',
};
```

which will set imageUrl state to props.user.avatar if props.user.avatar && props.user is true.

Comment: It's not correct. && evaluates condition and if props.user is truthy returns props.user.avatar. It's the same as props.user ? props.user.avatar : null;

Comment: @Simas.B Thanks for the tip. I have been writing extra code all these days

Comment: In the above code both props.user and props.user.avatar has to be true for the statement to return props.user.avatar. Otherwise it will return ' ' ... It work like that in the ternary operator. Everything before the ? has to evaluate to true if it should return props.user.avatar.